# Recursively reducing arrays using abstract methods [Java]?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm working on the following problem on my assignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOM1A.png

I'm having trouble with recursively reducing an array within a static method that applies an abstract method to the array. I'm unsure how to make the static method recursive. Here is what  I have so far

For my interface class I have the following:

```
public interface ReduceFun {
    public int f(int a, int b);
}
```

Classes that implement this:

```
class Add implements ReduceFun {

@Override
public int f(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

}

class Multiply implements ReduceFun {

@Override
public int f(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}

}

class Minus implements ReduceFun {

@Override
public int f(int a, int b) {
    return 2*b - a;
}

}
```

The static method in my driver class is:

```
public static int ReduceArray(ReduceFun w, int[] a){
    int total = 0;
    int temp;
    if (a.length == 1)
    return a[0];
    else 
        for(int i=a.length-1; i > 0; i--)
            if (i==1)
                return w.f(a[0], a[1]); //Base Case
            else
                //Stuck here
    return total;
}
```

I tried calling `total = total + ReduceArray(w, a);`, which lead to an overflow error because it pretty much leads nowhere since the parameters don't keep track of the index. I was also thinking of creating a `int[] b` that is `int[] a` but with one less index. This way, I can keep track of the index, but I'm also stuck on what to make the return statement. I'd appreciate any and all help

Comment: What you are (possibly) looking for is: `total = w.f(a[i], total)` or something similar. And as for the initial value of `total`, you might need to implementing it like: `int total = w.getIntitialValue()`. (Because for `Multiply` you nmight want `total` to be initialized with `1` instead of `0`).

Comment: Please don't ask the same questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681302/reducing-arrays-with-recursive-abstract-methods

Comment: You could add another `ReduceArray` overload that also takes an index as an argument, and use that to track the current element.

Comment: @Tunaki it's very similar, but different.

Comment: Okay, in that one, there was a typo that was corrected here...

Comment: @JornVernee For the purpose of this assignment, I can't introduce another function

Comment: @SuperSaiyan I tried `total = w.f(a[i], total); but it returned 5, and it should return 17. I think it's because there's no actual recursion going on in here, it is just w.f(5, 0), since total was initialized as 0. Is there anything wrong with my for loop?